# A simple post request wont route to a web api control

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This the configuration of the routing in WebApiConfig.cs

```
// Web API configuration and services
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ActionApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}");
// Web API routes



config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultAdpi",
  routeTemplate: "api/ms/{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "MSApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/ms/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller="GPI" }
);
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

This is my controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult payout(string t)
    {
```

This is the httpRequest

```
POST /api/Race/payout HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1
Content-Length: 4
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Postman-Token: f2adaf2e-d518-4924-bd28-8a901bd1846f
X-Forwarded-For: 84.228.5.88
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Original-Host: integerator.eu.ngrok.io

t=da
```

I have a few functions in this controller. There is no problem with the name of the controller. The actions get called.

A bit more details. If I use the [FromBody] attribute, I get the t value being a null.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult payout([FromBody]string t)
    {
```

The t variable is null.

I must have the t as a string variable. I dont want to change it to another type.

Please help me understand that awkward routing behavior.

**Update**

I have the following two actions:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult payout(string t)
    {
```

and

```
   public IHttpActionResult payout([FromBody] Object req)
        {
```

The http request that I mentioned would always go to the second payout action and not the first action. 
I want that post request to be intercepted by the first action with the string parameter. 
I dont understand why the request is not handled by the first action. That is even when the second action is completely removed.

I tried to post different http content type headers with a tool that is called 'Post man'.

This is the error that I get when I have the first action in the controller only,

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55392/api/Race/payout'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Race' that 

matches the request."
}
```

I considered overriding the model binding with object, the way it is described here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api
```

But I dont think that anything there is relevant. Is there a way to hack the way the routing works and intercept the incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must use `FromBody` attribute in this case, because `string` is a simple type that is deserialized from the Url by default. Check article [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) for the details. Otherwise, as far as you don't have a route that could match missing `t` parameter, you'll get 404 error.

Howerver as you noted in your question you'll get null value in `t` variable if `FromBody` is used. When you send form-urlencoded data, ASP.NET Web Api uses `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` for deserializing request data. This formatter does his job by mapping key-values from the request to properties or fields of the holding object. So if you declare following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string T { get; set; }
}
```

and change your action to

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult payout([FromBody] SomeClass obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

and send the same request, you will get `obj` instance with `T` property filled with `"da"` value.

With default form-urlencoded media type formatter, you can't send the same request and deserialize the data directly to string variable.

Here are your options for keeping the action with string variable deserialized from the body:

1. Change request content-type to `application/json` and send the following data in the request body (the quotes around the value are required):

   "da"

   `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` will correctly deserialize such string value.
2. If you want to keep content type, then you should implement custom media type formatter for form-urlencoded data that will deserialize directly to the string. There are a lot of examples how to implement custom formatter. Here are some of them:

   [Simple Custom Media Formatter in ASP.Net Web API](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/simple-custom-media-formatter-in-asp-net-web-api/)

   [Creating Custom CSVMediaTypeFormatter In ASP.NET Web API for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Format](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/creating-custom-csvmediatypeformatter-in-asp-net-web-api-for-comma-separated-values-csv-format)

Hope this will help.

Comment: There is a a better solution that I wanted to ask. But before that, I do have post controllers that accept post requests and have simple types such as string, int, decimal etc. Their parameters bind to the request parameters. I want the controller to identify between different objects. When the request arrives each controller with any object parameter is for the routing system.. so it throws an error of 'multiple action existing to handle' the request. Another thing, I am not trying to deserialize a json. It is a simple http post request.I also dont think I need a formatter that works globally

Comment: I also post from Postman. No content type makes the request work. I also dont have influence over the request parameters because I work with external api provider.

Comment: Your comments do not relate to your original question. Consider asking a new question for the case you described.

Comment: Well, you have added a completely new question to the first one. That's a bad practice.

Comment: I thought the question was very simple to understand. It was about simply routing a post request to a post controller with a string parameter. So can you give me a direction to the answer?